# How to enable multiple Entrybox with multiple CheckButton?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter.checkbutton

I am trying to link each individual checkbutton to a specific entrybox using function. but i have no idea how to name each individual checkbuttons. coding is new to me and i need help desperately...

tried using a function found online but only the last entrybox is affected the checkbuttons

```
from tkinter import *

#initialise intial window, root
root = Tk()

dishes = Text(root, cursor="arrow")

qty = Text(root, cursor="arrow")

dishes.pack(side=RIGHT)
qty.pack(side=LEFT)


#to display a entrybox each row
for i in range(10):

    ent = Entry(root, width=3, state='disabled')
    qty.window_create("100.0", window=ent)
    qty.insert("end", "\n")

##to display a checkbutton each row
for key in range(10):

    var = IntVar(value=0)
    cb = Checkbutton(dishes, text="%d" % key,
                     variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    dishes.window_create("end", window=cb)
    dishes.insert("end", "\n")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suspect using a list of list would work well here.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the entries and variables in an array, and reference them using an index, assuming there's a 1:1 relationship between the entry and the checkbutton.

For the entries:

```
entries = []
for i in range(10):
    ent = Entry(root, width=3, state='disabled')
    entries.append(ent)
    ...
```

For the checkbutton variables:

```
vars = []
for key in range(10):
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    cb = Checkbutton(..., command=lambda i=key: set_state(i))
    ...
```

For the command to change the state:

```
def set_state(i):
    new_state = "disabled" if vars[i].get() == 0 else "normal"
    entries[i].configure(state=new_state)
```